# How to change nested object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I have a object like this.

```
var Obj = {
    obj1 : {
        val : 1,
        id : 1
    }
    obj2 : {
        val : 2,
        id :2
    }
    obj3 : {
        val : 3,
        id :3
    }
}
```

I want my `obj1`and all sub object into one array so I can retrieve the value. I want array in array because I want to retrieve them, Since it is dynamic I can not use `Obj.obj1` therefore I want to push into array.

Can Anybody tell How Can I get that. Thanks for help

Comment: What have you tried? It's also unclear what you want the output to look like. Do you want the output to just be `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods to convert it to an array but the order is not guaranteed since object properties don't have any order.

```js
var Obj = {
  obj1: {
    val: 1,
    id: 1
  },
  obj2: {
    val: 2,
    id: 2
  },
  obj3: {
    val: 3,
    id: 3
  }
};

var res = Object.keys(Obj).map(function(k) {
    return Obj[k];
  })

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `Object.values(Obj)` is another option (though browser support is lower)

Comment: @4castle :  It's not widely supported

Comment: @4castle That works fine, But any suggestion how to delete this record from the object. eg : `if(arr[I].val = 1)` then I want to delete `Obj1` mean respective object from the main object.

Comment: @David : use delete keyword

Comment: @PranavCBalan sir ya Let me try your code. give me few min.

Comment: @PranavCBalan so in this case I got array like array[0,1,2]. Now I after condition I get to know I need to delete 0 index so I remove from array, but how can I delete this from main Object. Which is Obj1. I can use `delete Object.Obj1` but how it is linked with array[0]

Comment: @David : keep the reference for that ( corresponding property name of each index ) ...... to delete `delete Obj[keys[0]]` ... where `keys` contains property names corresponding to each array object

Comment: Thanks a ton. Work like a charm.